# RemoteException occurs on reporting focusChanged

Tags: element

I use shared elements to jump from a small picture to a large picture preview activity. The large picture preview activity uses viewpager. When I slide, the following exceptions occasionally appear. Does anyone know why

```
WindowManager: RemoteException occurs on reporting focusChanged, w=Window{3cba58b u0/bigpic.PicturePlayActivity}
    android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:527)
        at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.windowFocusChanged(IWindow.java:829)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowSenter code enter code hereheretate.reportFocusChangedSerialized(WindowState.java:3685)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:5262)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: @ shaohui93 , Bhunnu Baba ,   I am facing same issue, any solution on this ?